# migrating TFS 2012 from phisical machine to VM

Tags: virtual-machine

we are about to move TFS from phisical machine to Virtual. The machnie includes both application and Data Tier.
The rollback plan is to turn off the vm and turn on the Phisical machine.
Does anybody had issues with this process? or changes that needed to be done?. the machine will have the same name but diffrent IP.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from physical machine to virtual went smoothly. I stopped the collection before the migration and started them back after and everything worked the same on all users stations.